# Spark Dataframe change column value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I got some dataframe with 170 columns. In one column I have a "name" string and this string sometimes can have a special symbols like "'" that are not appropriate, when I am writing them to Postgres.
Can I make something like that:

```
Df[$'name']=Df[$'name'].map(x => x.replaceAll("'","")) ?
```

I don't want to parse full DataFrame,because it's very huge.Help me please

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can't mutate DataFrames, you can only transform them into new DataFrames with updated values. In this case - you can use the `regex_replace` function to perform the mapping on `name` column:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val updatedDf = Df.withColumn("name", regexp_replace(col("name"), ",", ""))
```

Comment: i have a similar problem however there is a certain list of values that I have in an array: val ids  = Array("1e4f199c", "6681b1b0"). I have to check if the column "id" has a value that is in ids only then the value is replaced otherwise the previous value is retained. what do I do then?

Comment: @SimpleFellow you can try using the functions `when` and `isin` from `org.apache.spark.sql.functions` - if you need help understanding exactly how, feel free to post a new question, a bit too much to answer in a comment.

Comment: here it is, the complete program:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48627959/how-to-update-few-records-in-spark

Comment: What if I need to edit columns A and B by having condition on column C and D?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this

```
df.withColumn("name", when($"name" === "'", ""))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.withColumn("name",  lit(translate( translate(col("cpf"), ".", ""),"-","")))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it